# Getting org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector": error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing automation testing and new in this field. I am getting error like:

> "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable
> to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"

When if condition gets failed. The `else if` and `else` part is not getting executed.

Below is Object Class:

public class createNewItemObjects extends BaseClass{

```
CommonActions commonActions = new CommonActions();
ReadAndWriteProperties readwriteprop = new ReadAndWriteProperties();

int totalItems = commonActions.getExcelRowNumbers(readwriteprop.getCompletePropertyCreationExcelPath(), readwriteprop.getItemsMenusTextDataSheetName());
static int i = 0;


//Constructor to initialize all web elements located by @FindBy annotation.
public createNewItemObjects(){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

//'New Item' button
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='new00N1U000006qwz9']")
public WebElement newItemBtn;

//'Item Record Type' DDB
@FindBy(xpath = "//select[@id='p3']")
WebElement itemRecordTypeDDB;

//'Continue' button
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@value='Continue']")
WebElement continueBtn;

//'Item Name' text box
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='Name']")
WebElement itemNameTxtBox;

//'Revenue Classification' Lookup button
@FindBy(xpath = "//img[@alt='Revenue Classification Lookup (New Window)']")
WebElement revenueClassificationLookupBtn;

//'Search Frame' on Lookup window
@FindBy(xpath = "//frame[@name='searchFrame']")
WebElement searchFrameName;

//'Revenue Classification' search box
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='pBody']//input[@id='lksrch']")
WebElement revenueClassificationsSearchBox;

//'Go' button
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@title='Go!']")
WebElement goBtn;

//'Result Frame' on Lookup window
@FindBy(xpath = "//frame[@name='resultsFrame']")
WebElement resultFrame;

//Revenue Classification 'Food'
@FindBy(linkText = "Food")
WebElement revenueClassificationNameFoodLinkTxt;

//Revenue Classification 'Beverage'
@FindBy(linkText = "Beverage")
WebElement revenueClassificationNameBeverageLinkTxt;

//'Quantity Calculation' DDB
@FindBy(xpath = "//select[@name='00N1U000006qwzC']")
WebElement quantityCalculationDDB;

//'Save' button
@FindBy(xpath = "//td[@id='bottomButtonRow']//input[@name='save']")
WebElement saveItemBtn;

//'Save and New' button
@FindBy(xpath = "//td[@id='topButtonRow']//input[@name='save_new']")
WebElement saveAndNewItemBtn;

//Property name after clicking on 'Save' Item button
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='Name_ileinner']")
WebElement itemNm;



//Method for clicking on 'New Item' button
public void newItemButton(){
    
    //Click on 'New Item' button.
    newItemBtn.click();
}

//Method for adding multiple Items
public void addNewItem(String selectItemRecordType, String itemName, String wildCard, 
        String foodRevenueClassificationsName, String beverageRevenueClassificationsName, 
        String quantityCalculationPerPerson){

    //Explicit wait to visible the Text
    commonActions.waitForVisibility(itemRecordTypeDDB);

    //Select Item Record Type from DDB
    Select chooseItemRecordType = new Select(itemRecordTypeDDB);
    chooseItemRecordType.selectByVisibleText(selectItemRecordType);

    //Click on 'Continue' button.
    continueBtn.click();

    //Enter 'Item' name.
    itemNameTxtBox.sendKeys(itemName);
    String enteredItemName = itemNameTxtBox.getAttribute("value");

    //Parent window id
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //Explicit wait to visible the Text
    commonActions.waitForVisibility(revenueClassificationLookupBtn);

    //Click on 'Revenue Classification' lookup button.
    revenueClassificationLookupBtn.click();

    //Explicit wait for 'Number of Windows'
    commonActions.waitForNumberOfWindows();

    //To get all window's ids
    Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for(String childWindow:allWindows){

        if(!childWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(parentWindow)){

            //Focus on Child window.
            driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);

            //Focus on 'Search Frame' window.
            driver.switchTo().frame(searchFrameName);

            //Explicit wait to visible the Text
            commonActions.waitForVisibility(revenueClassificationsSearchBox);

            //Clear the text box
            revenueClassificationsSearchBox.clear();
            
            //Explicit wait to visible the Text
            commonActions.waitForVisibility(revenueClassificationsSearchBox);
            
            //Enter 'Wildcard' symbols
            revenueClassificationsSearchBox.sendKeys(wildCard);

            //Explicit wait to visible the Text
            commonActions.waitForVisibility(goBtn);

            //Click on 'Go' button.
            goBtn.click();

            //Focus on 'Main' window.
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

            //Explicit wait to visible the Text
            commonActions.waitForVisibility(resultFrame);

            //Focus on 'Result Frame' window.
            driver.switchTo().frame(resultFrame);

            //Explicit wait to visible the Text
            commonActions.waitForVisibility(revenueClassificationNameFoodLinkTxt);

            //Click on 'Food' Revenue Classification.
            if(enteredItemName.equalsIgnoreCase(foodRevenueClassificationsName)){
                revenueClassificationNameFoodLinkTxt.click();
            }
            //Click on 'Beverage' Revenue Classification.
            else if(enteredItemName.equalsIgnoreCase(beverageRevenueClassificationsName)){
                revenueClassificationNameBeverageLinkTxt.click();
            }
        }
    }

    //Focus on Parent window.
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);

    //Select 'Quantity Calculation' from DDB.
    Select quantityCalculation = new Select(quantityCalculationDDB);
    quantityCalculation.selectByVisibleText(quantityCalculationPerPerson);

    if(i < totalItems)
    {
        saveAndNewItemBtn.click();
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else{
        saveItemBtn.click();
        commonActions.waitForVisibility(itemNm);
    }
}

//Method to compare with 'Available Item Record Types' static text 
public String getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn(){
    String availableItemRecordTypesTxt = "";
    try{
        ***availableItemRecordTypesTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='recordTypesHeading']")).getText();***
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException exp){
        System.out.println("This is exception message " + exp);
    }
    return availableItemRecordTypesTxt;
}

//Method to compare with 'Property' name 
public String getitenNameAfterSaveButton(){
    String itenNameAfterSaveButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Name_ileinner']")).getText();
    return itenNameAfterSaveButton;
}
```

}

**Below is the Test Class:**

public class TC_CreateNewItem extends BaseClass {

```
CreateNewItemObjects createNewItem;
ReadAndWriteProperties readwriteprop = new ReadAndWriteProperties();
CommonActions commonActions;

@Test(priority = 1)
public void clickNewItemButton(){

    createNewItem = new CreateNewItemObjects();
    commonActions = new CommonActions();

    commonActions.waitForVisibility(createNewItem.newItemBtn);
    createNewItem.newItemButton();
}


@Test(priority = 2, dataProvider = "getNewItemCreationDataThroughExcel")
public void addNewItemsForProperty(String selectItemRecordTypeDDL, String itemNm, String wildCardSymbols, 
        String revenueClassificationsNameFood, String revenueClassificationsNameBeverage, String quantityCalculationEachPerson, 
        String availableItemRecordTypesText, String itenNameAfterSaveBttn){

    createNewItem = new createNewItemObjects();

    //Executing Object class method
    createNewItem.addNewItem(selectItemRecordTypeDDL, itemNm, wildCardSymbols, revenueClassificationsNameFood, 
            revenueClassificationsNameBeverage, quantityCalculationEachPerson);

    //Checking whether 'Available Item Record Types' or 'Property Name' available or not
    try{
        ***if(createNewItem.getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn().equalsIgnoreCase(availableItemRecordTypesText)){***
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
            logger().info("Item is created successfully.");
        }
        else if(createNewItem.getitenNameAfterSaveButton().equalsIgnoreCase(itenNameAfterSaveBttn)){
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
            logger().info("Item is created succussfully.");
        }
        else{
            logger().warn("Item creation is failed.");
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exp){
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//The 'DataProvider' annotation to fetch the data from excel.
@DataProvider
public Object[][] getNewItemCreationDataThroughExcel(){
    return ReadAndWriteExcel.getExcelData(readwriteprop.getCompletePropertyCreationExcelPath(), readwriteprop.getItemsMenusTextDataSheetName());
}
```

}

**Error Code:**

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h3[@class='recordTypesHeading']"}
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DATTAC-WIN8', ip: '10.75.8.53', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 84.0.4147.125, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\dattac\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:63652}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: none, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 6543ce8946621a7081bac5786eabaf73
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h3[@class='recordTypesHeading']}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
at com.test.qa.pageobjects.CreateNewItemObjects.getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn(CreateNewItemObjects.java:191)
at com.test.qa.testcases.TC_CreateNewItem_0007.addNewItemsForProperty(TC_CreateNewItem_0007.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

Comment: No such element means selenium cannot find your element.  It can be sync related or your identifier might be wrong. Can you please share your lower level code i.e. the xpath that's failling and can you either add the html or provide a link to the application under test (or both)

Comment: I am adding 7 Items and there are two buttons. One is 'Save and New' and second is 'New'. When script adds 6 items then 'if' code block works fine. But when script clicks on 'Save' button for 7th Item then code should skip 'if' code block and should run 'else if' code block. When script clicks on 'Save' button then UI is different and there is no 'Save and New' button is available. And script searches 'if' block on that UI and throw such error.

Comment: How can we help? - we don't know what `availableItemRecordTypesText` is or it's value, and we don't know what `getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn()` does, we don't know what you application looks like and we don't know the structure of the DOM - if what you say is right, it's entering the if block because of these components.  All i can tell you is the error selenium provides is that it cannot find your element. Unless you share all the relevant code and the html for the application under test no one will know :-)

Comment: Provided both Object and Test classes. If you need anything else please let me know,

Comment: Rich, Thanks for your efforts. But issue is not resolved after applying your solution too. I tell you the complete test case in layman language. Hope this will help to resolve my issue.

1 - User clicks on 'New Item' button on Homepage.
2 - User lands to inside the page.
3 - Here inside the page, there is 'Item Record Type' dropdown box and 'Continue & Cancel' buttons.
4 - User selects one of the values from 'Item Record Type' dropdown box and clicks on 'Continue' button.
5 - Now user lands on 'Item Details' page. There are three buttons (Save, Save & New, Cancel) on this page.

Comment: 6 - User fills item information and clicks on 'Save & New' button as he has to add multiple items.
7 - When user clicks on 'Save & New', item gets added and user lands on 'Step No 3'. Here, user again selects one of the values from 'Item Record Type' dropdown box and clicks on 'Continue' button.
8 - Again he/she lands on 'Item Details' page where three buttons (Save, Save & New, Cancel) are available.
9 - User repeats above scenarios 6 times.
10 - When user fills information for 7th item then he/she clicks on 'Save' button as there are no more items need to add.

Comment: 11 - Once user clicks on 'Save' button, item gets added and last items information gets displayed in read-only mode with the buttons 'Edit, Delete, Cancel'.

So when user is adding 6 items then 'getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn()' method will call in 'If' condition but when he/she adds 7th item then 'getitenNameAfterSaveButton()' method should call which is in 'Else if' condition. In this scenario 'If' condition should skip as condition is not satisfied and move to 'else if' condition code block.

Comment: My test case is getting passed without log info which is available in 'else if' condition (logger().info("Item is created successfully.")) but throwing exception for 'if' condition as "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"

Comment: I think the answer is still in my solution.... your comment : "will call in 'If' condition but when he/she adds 7th item then 'getitenNameAfterSaveButton()' method should call which is in 'Else if' condition.**In this scenario 'If' condition should skip** as condition is not satisfied"  - that' i not right. The IF is called, it goes to the low level function, and tries to find the object - selenium cannot find the object and returns nosuchelement and the test terminates. As per the answer below, you need to handle that error.  That is what i understood based on your original post.

Comment: You say the `if` fails with nosuchelement,  so this xpath`"//div[@id='Name_ileinner']"` is not found - and you need to handle it.  If i'm not right please share tell me which line of code is failing, and the FULL error  (you stop your error paste before it says what identifier is not found)

Comment: I have added the complete FULL error. Kindly check.

Comment: I have added 3 star before and end of the code where I am getting an error.

Comment: Did you import the correct NoSuchElementException? I can see your modified code has it handled.... you need the one from openQA ?   - if you're not sure which you have try and update to this `catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException exp){`

Comment: Previously, I imported 'NoSuchElementException from incorrect class. Now, as suggested by you, imported from 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException' class. Now after executing the script, even though it is giving an 'NoSuchElementException' exception, the 'else if' code block is getting executed and test case showing as passed. THANK YOU SO MUCH for your valuable and consistent support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your failing because you're not handling the exception.

Every time you call this line:

```
if(createNewItem.getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn().equalsIgnoreCase(availableItemRecordTypesText)){
```

You're running this method:

```
//Method to compare with 'Available Item Record Types' static text 
public String getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn(){
    String availableItemRecordTypesTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='recordTypesHeading']")).getText();
    return availableItemRecordTypesTxt;
}
```

In your comments you say you're doing this 7 times and it fails on the last iteration because the text is not present. You say:

> When script clicks on 'Save' button then UI is different and there is
> no 'Save and New' button is available.

*I think* you're expecting because this method is in an `IF` (from the first code block), if the object doesn't exist it will return nothing. However, selenium does not work that way.

What is actually happening is you are asking seleneium to see if the element is present and if selenium cannot find the object it throws the `NoSuchElementException`

The best way to use selenium is to program your code for expected objects only. Checking for objects-**not**-being-present is more difficult as you need to ensure you've sufficiently waited (implicit or explicit wait time) for the page to be ready and all scripts to be executed and complete with all data returned. This typically incurs time penalties in scripts. If you don't wait this full amount of time you can get *false-passes* which is very bad in the world of testing. For example, lets say you set implicit wait of 30 seconds - and want to verify an element is not present, this has to wait to the full 30 seconds every time you call it. If that method is then called by multiple scripts then the overall execution time quickly multiplies up.

That said - if you want a QUICK solution. Add error handling to your code as such:

```
public String getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn(){
    //create a new blank string
    String availableItemRecordTypesTxt = "";
    try 
    {
        // only set the string if the object exists
         availableItemRecordTypesTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='recordTypesHeading']")).getText();
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
    {
       //Allow this error the be thrown but not stop your test
       //error handle here - e.g. reporting or another action
    }
    return availableItemRecordTypesTxt;
}
```

This will allow your object to error and the method to return no text if it's not present, and in theory, allow it to progress to the next if.

---

Update following the comments.

The error handling looks in place but it didn't capture the exception.
I believe you've added the wrong exception. Be explicit and substitute in this line in your lower level method:

```
catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException exp){
```

I've run some code on  a cut down version of the problem.
I added an xpath that clearly won't exist and the code catches the error and returns no text.

This is the code:

```
 @Test
    public void demo()
    {
        String WhatIsTheReturn = getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn();
        System.out.println("the return is... " + WhatIsTheReturn);
    }

    public String getavailableItemRecordTypesTxtAfterSaveAndNewBtn(){
        String availableItemRecordTypesTxt = "";
        try{
            availableItemRecordTypesTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='I do not exist']")).getText();
        }
        catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException exp){
            System.out.println("Excpetion was handled!");
        }
        return availableItemRecordTypesTxt;
    }
```

This is the output (exception caught, return is nothing)

> Excpetion was handled!
>
> the return is...

Answer (score -1):

Probably wrong selector value.
Try using selenium [IDE](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/) to interact with that specific element then use the selector the IDE shows.